# IBM MQ connection in node js with 2 way SSL

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-mq

I'm trying to establish 2 way SSL MQ connection from node js application via 'ibmmq' node module. Is it possible to configure truststore and keystore (SSL configs) with ibmmq? If so, how should it be configured?

Answer (score 0):

See comments in the amqsconntls.js sample.

As it's built on the C client, the Node.js layer requires a kdb-format store which combines the role of keystore and truststore. Use of that store from client programs is described in the MQ knowledgecenter - various mechanisms including program-specified, ini file and environment variables can be used to access it depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I'll convert my private key (.p12) (keystore) file to .kdb. But how shall I add the server cert file (Truststore) for the configuration?

Comment: kdb files contain both personal certs and signers. The strmqikm, runmqakm and runmqckm commands can be used - depending on what you've installed - to import both types. Again, read the MQ documentation on managing kdb files.